# What is the best solution to CSS div overflow problem?

Tags: html, css

There is a box and there are announcements in it. But the announcement carries it out of the box. What can I do for it? I use Marquee.

*HTML*

```
<div class="vertical-marquee right-page hidden-xs">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <p style="font-size: 30px; color: #d6750a;" v-for="announcement in announcements">{{ announcement }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.right-page {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px #588db7 solid;
  margin-top: 183px;
  margin-right: -190px;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

[image: Here is the image of the problem]

Comment: what is your expected OP

Comment: What is the OP?

Comment: I think you can just add `max-height: 100%; overflow: auto;` to div `<div style="position: absolute;">`.

Comment: Yes, It's worked! @acbay

Answer (score 4):

try code below and see if it works for you.

```css
.right-page {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px #588db7 solid;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    resize: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="vertical-marquee right-page hidden-xs">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <p style="font-size: 30px; color: #d6750a;" v-for="announcement in announcements">There is a box and there are announcements in it. But the announcement carries it out of the box. What can I do for it? I use Marquee.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow: hidden; for this

```
.right-page {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px #588db7 solid;
  margin-top: 183px;
  margin-right: -190px;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}
```